# Python file :ImportError: No module named win32com.client in eclipse. But same file works in command prompt

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Error:
`ImportError: No module named win32com.client` when I execute `.py` file in eclipse. It works fine when it is executed using command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you have multiple python installations and the interpreter which is mapped with eclipse doesn't have the library.

Run following both on command prompt and eclipse, see if there any differences

```
import sys
print sys.path
```